# Saving a list of objects using numpy.save. then delete the package that contains the class of each object

Tags: python, database, numpy, oop

For example, if I have a class `C` from package `P`, then I create a list:

`L = [ C() for i in range(10) ]`

, then I save using `numpy.save('filename', L)`, then of course I can reuse the objects in the list `L`.

But if then I uninstall the package `P`, will I still be able to reuse the objects?

Thanks.

*Say, for example, `C` is a `matplotlib.patches.Circle` class, but then I uninstall Matplotlib.

Comment: `np.save` uses `pickle` to serialize non-array objects.  In the case of a list of objects, it will make an array from the list, and then pickle all the elements.  Read the `pickle` documentation to see what's required for `unpickling`.  Class instance data is saved, but not the class code or methods.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

Comment: @hpaulj But the objects functionality were created via the class code. So the answer is they are still reusable? I can still use any methods of the object?

Comment: Go ahead test things for your self.  The best answers demonstrate what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @hpaulj Then I have to uninstall a package. There must be a statement or rule about the language (Python) that answers the question. How Python works in this case.